# Rviz in MoveIt setup assisstant not loading

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros melodic. I am new to ros and was learning moveit. While loading the model into setup assisstant, it shows the successful loading of the model but the rviz panel on the right is blank for me. Can anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362770/rviz-in-moveit-setup-assisstant-not-loading/) by [omkar_a_k](https://answers.ros.org/users/58173/omkar_a_k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As noted in [the cross-posted Github issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2345) this is a bug that is fixed in the next release. In the meantime, you can build moveit from source. The packages you build in your workspace take precedence over the ones installed in `/opt/ros/melodic`.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-05**:
@fvd: if you encounter someone cross-posting like this, it'd be best to close the question here, instead of posting an answer. A comment would then suffice to let the poster know that cross-posting is not very nice, and that he/she should wait for a reponse on their initial post.